# How to encode a column with high cardinality?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I'm trying to find a way to encode a column that i have that , basically contains , different degrees in different domains , ans i was thinking , what could be the best way to encode it.

```
  df['Ultima_Formazione'].value_counts()

   PhD |    Mathematics                                                                                                             2824
   Master's degree in Management Engineering                                                                                     2794
   Laurea Magistrale in Scienze Statistiche per le Decisioni | CdL Magistrale in Scienze Statistiche per le Decisioni LM-82 |    2791
   Master's degree | Geographic Information Science and Cartography | 110/110 | Master's degree                                   472
   Elettronica e     Telecomunicazioni                                                                                                468
   Master in Business Intelligence e Big Data Analytics                                                                           371
   Physics                                                                                                                        364
   Laurea Magistrale  LM | Scienze statistiche ed economiche |                                                                    360
   Laurea | Informatica                                                                                                           316
   Management |                                                                                                                   300
   Master's degree | Master in Marketing & Service Management |                                                                   267
   Informatica Applicata | Informatica                                                                                            265
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .


   Name: Ultima_Formazione, Length: 329, dtype: int64
```

I've been reading since this morning about the best approach , but , none of them convinced me , the one hot encoding is definitely not an option , embeddings Using Deep Learning is very tempting , but i don't think it will work , giving the structure of my column.

any suggestion , would be much appreciated , thank u.

Comment: Encode it as 1,2,3,...? As they are unstructured, any encoding will do. Also what are trying to model?

Comment: I'm Trying to develop a model to predict if a current person will get hired as a Data Scientist.

Comment: a) (sarcasm) he will not, b) try to disentangle the column into two: field and level of education